# Adaptive Cards Input Toggle(CheckBox) IOS issue

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We have created bot using Microsoft bot-framework which is integrated to Microsoft teams. We have created few adaptive cards for interactive conversation with bot. One of the Adaptive card is causing design issue in IPhone X Microsoft Teams Application.

We used Adaptive card template for building this card which displays the list of Tasks along with status of the task. Each task has Input.Toggle (Checkbox) and at the end a button will be displayed. When Checkbox's are selected and button is clicked [image: Sample Image Reference]

We are sending new card with task details where they can edit the status and so on. Please find the JSON data below.

Card Payload Editor Json Data:

```
    {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "border": true,
            "items": [
                {
                    "$data": "{properties}",
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "auto",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "id": "{id}",
                                    "type": "Input.Toggle",
                                    "title": " ",
                                    "value": "false",
                                    "wrap": false
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Container",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "FactSet",
                                            "facts": [
                                                {
                                                    "$data": "{peers}",
                                                    "title": "{key}",
                                                    "value": "{value}"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "style": "emphasis"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "{actionSubmitTitle}",
            "horizontalAlignment": "center"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
    }
```

Sample Data Editor:

```
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"InputToggle1",
         "peers":[
            {
               "key":"Project",
               "value":"' .$task->project_name. '"
            },
            {
               "key":"Task",
               "value":"'.$task->id.' - '.$task->heading.'"
            },
            {
               "key":"Status",
               "value":"'.$task->board_column.'"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"InputToggle2",
         "peers":[
            {
               "key":"Project",
               "value":"' .$task->project_name. '"
            },
            {
               "key":"Task",
               "value":"'.$task->id.' - '.$task->heading.'"
            },
            {
               "key":"Status",
               "value":"'.$task->board_column.'"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"InputToggle3",
         "peers":[
            {
               "key":"Project",
               "value":"' .$task->project_name. '"
            },
            {
               "key":"Task",
               "value":"'.$task->id.' - '.$task->heading.'"
            },
            {
               "key":"Status",
               "value":"'.$task->board_column.'"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"InputToggle4",
         "peers":[
            {
               "key":"Project",
               "value":"' .$task->project_name. '"
            },
            {
               "key":"Task",
               "value":"'.$task->id.' - '.$task->heading.'"
            },
            {
               "key":"Status",
               "value":"'.$task->board_column.'"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "actionSubmitTitle":"Update Timesheet"
}
```

The InputToggle is inside the column set with **width** as **auto** and it is perfectly rendering in [Microsoft Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ahYn.png) and   [Android App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opo9i.jpg)  but whereas in [IOS app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9MLP.png) it is not showing

When we set the **width** property to **stretch**, InputToggle is getting displayed in [IOS App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHGaH.png) in big size but in [Desktop App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojihc.png) and [Android App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvSxF.png) the column is pushing and occupying much space.

Please help me so that we can display the Input.Toggle in IOS Microsoft Teams without breaking the design in Desktop and Android Teams App.

**Edit**: Adding final JSON sent to the bot. The columns in the column set will be changed dynamically based on the ask list in database.

```
{
   "type":"AdaptiveCard",
   "version":"1.0",
   "body":[
      {
         "type":"Container",
         "border":true,
         "items":[
            {
               "type":"ColumnSet",
               "columns":[
                  {
                     "type":"Column",
                     "width":"auto",
                     "items":[
                        {
                           "id":"inputToggle1",
                           "type":"Input.Toggle",
                           "title":" ",
                           "value":"false",
                           "wrap":false
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"Column",
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "items":[
                        {
                           "type":"Container",
                           "items":[
                              {
                                 "type":"FactSet",
                                 "facts":[
                                    {
                                       "title":"Project",
                                       "value":"Project 1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "title":"Task",
                                       "value":"Task 1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "title":"Status",
                                       "value":"Pending"
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ],
                           "style":"emphasis"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"ColumnSet",
               "columns":[
                  {
                     "type":"Column",
                     "width":"auto",
                     "items":[
                        {
                           "id":"inputToggle2",
                           "type":"Input.Toggle",
                           "title":" ",
                           "value":"false",
                           "wrap":false
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"Column",
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "items":[
                        {
                           "type":"Container",
                           "items":[
                              {
                                 "type":"FactSet",
                                 "facts":[
                                    {
                                       "title":"Project",
                                       "value":"Project 1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "title":"Task",
                                       "value":" Task 2"
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "title":"Status",
                                       "value":"Completed"
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ],
                           "style":"emphasis"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "actions":[
      {
         "type":"Action.Submit",
         "title":"Update Timesheet",
         "horizontalAlignment":"center"
      }
   ],
   "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you have design inconsistencies like those its often a problem with the host, in this case the ios app. If the card looks like you want everywhere else its more than likely a bug

Comment: Could you please share the final adaptive card json being sent along with the screenshots of both desktop and iOS client?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already added the link of screenshots in Desktop, Android and IOS app with width as auto and stretch respectively. With width as auto, the design is perfect as expected in desktop and android but in ios it is failing.

I edited my answer for adding the final JSON

Comment: @Nagasai Thanks for reporting this. We could repro it and i have raised a bug for this.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample code on how you're displaying the data?

Comment: Hi @John, I already included the final JSON which we are sending to Microsoft Teams for displaying.

Comment: Hey, I'm able to send the data but how do I display the sent data on ios?

Answer (score 1):

For completion, this was caused by a bug and is tracked as an Github Issue here:

https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/4052#